# console.log not shown in my local terminal

Tags: node.js, express

In my server site all works fine. but When I checked anything by console. log('anything') it doesn't show.
here are some codes. they work fine. only I cannot see the console.log.

```
function varifyToken(req, res, next) {
    const getToken = req.headers.authorization;
    console.log('gettoken',getToken);
    next();
}
```

Comment: We need more info on how you have your stuff setup, are you 100% certain your `varifyToken` *which is spelled verify* is getting run at all? Are your piping stdout somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should use something like this

```
function varifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const getToken = req.get('authorization');
  console.log('gettoken',getToken);
next();
```

}

Please check [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get)

Comment: Thanks. 
but still now> console.log('getToken') don't show in my local terminal;
updated Code is but my project work fine
------------------- 
function varifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const getToken = req.get('authorization');
  console.log('gettoken',getToken);
next();